# Simple shopping cart/paypal payments implementation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce

I'd like to know from your experience what is the best way to use to setup a simple online store using paypal for payments. My site will be selling prints so there's not many catergories or items, so I'm looking for the easiest to implement solution...I had a look at spree and rorecommerce but both seem overcomplicated for my needs.

Comment: Just curious what is over-complicated with ror_ecommerce?  BTW I created it.  =)  I love all feedback (bad or good) I'd love to help out even if you go with your own solution.  Dave

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented such a system and found that implementing paypal with custom code is lot better than using any other gem or plugin for this.

If you follow railscasts here - http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=paypal
it does exactly the same thing and is very straight forward. Go through paypal basics, paypal notification and paypal security episodes.